# tensorflow transform a (structured) dense matrix to sparse, when number of rows unknow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

My task is to transform a special formed dense matrix tensor into a sparse one. e.g. input matrix M as followed (dense positive integer sequence followed by 0 as padding in each row)

```
[[3  5  7  0]
[2  2  0  0]
[1  3  9  0]]
```

Additionally, given the non-padding length for each row, e.g. given by tensor L =

```
[3, 2, 3].
```

The desired output would be sparse tensor S.

```
SparseTensorValue(indices=array([[0, 0],[0, 1],[0, 2],[1, 0],[1, 1],[2, 0],[2, 1], [2, 2]]), values=array([3, 5, 7, 2, 2, 1, 3, 9], dtype=int32), shape=array([3, 4]))
```

This is useful in models where objects are described by variable-sized descriptors (S are then used in embedding_lookup_sparse to connect embeddings of descriptors.)

I am able to do it when number of M's row is known (by python loop and ops like slice and concat). However, M's row number here is determined by mini-batch size and could change (say in testing phase). Is there a good way to implement that? I am trying some control_flow_ops but haven't succeeded.

Thanks!!

Comment: Could  you clarify what exactly is the difficulty introduced by a changing M? Why the same slice and concat solution doesn't apply any more?

Comment: to clarify, when mb (mini-batch size) is known (a scalar), I used the following (pseudo) code: { for i in range(mb):   __update_indices(i);  __update_values(i); }. when mb is unknown or a tensor, mb can't be used in range( ).

Comment: Would tf.while_loop and maybe together with tf.cond (which accepts a tensor) solve the problem?